# Distributed table deleting partition

Tags: clickhouse

I have created replicated merge tree table as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE probe.a on cluster dwh (
instime UInt64,
psn UInt64
) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/probe/a', '{replica}') PARTITION BY instime ORDER BY (psn);
```

Then I created a distributed table as :

```sql
CREATE TABLE probe.a_distributed on cluster dwh (
instime UInt64,
psn UInt64
) ENGINE = Distributed(dwh,probe, a, rand());
```

I have then added macro in each server:

**Server 1**

```xml
<yandex>
    <macros replace="true">
        <shard>1</shard>
        <replica>server1.com</replica>
    </macros>
</yandex>
```

**Server 2**

```xml
<yandex>
    <macros replace="true">
        <shard>2</shard>
        <replica>server2.com</replica>
    </macros>
</yandex>
```

**Remote Servers:**

```xml
<dwh>
            <!-- shard 01 -->
            <shard>            
                <replica>
                    <host>server1.com</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>test12pwd</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>

            <!-- shard 02 -->
            <shard>            
                <replica>
                    <host>server2.com</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>test12pwd</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
 </dwh>
```

***I have two issues when dropping partition:***

1. When I drop partition using a distributed table

   ALTER TABLE probe.a on cluster dwh DROP PARTITION '2020-03-13';

I get error:

> DB::Exception: Table 'a' is replicated, but shard #4 isn't replicated
>   according to its cluster definition. Possibly
>   true is forgotten in the
>   cluster config. (version 19.16.14.65) (version 19.16.14.65)

2. Dropped partition individually but distributed table is showing half of the row still but when I check locally there is no row
     [image]

**How can this issue with distributed table be resolved for data sharded without replication?**

Comment: if I right understood your cluster consists of 2 shards and 2 replicas - it is wrong the count of replicas should be 2 or more per shard. You need to either add two extra servers so that each server stores one of two replicas of the shard (count of shards is 2) or use [circular topology](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse) to store two replicas on one server (it is not recommended way).

Comment: look at for details - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/2161#issuecomment-378197593

Comment: @vladimir, I only use two shard. No replication. Replication as of now is not needed. I just was data to be separated as the volume of data is high.

Comment: why table *probe.a* defined as *ReplicatedMergeTree* not *MergeTree*?

Comment: @vladimir , because it should be distributed table across 2 servers.

Comment: you said that you need only sharding, not replication so don't need to use *Replicated*-engine and don't use *macros.xml*.

Comment: @vladimir , what would be my create table statement like for local table?

Comment: it should be the same as now but use *MergeTree*-engine. Distributed-table + related cluster config leave without changes.

Comment: @vladimir , I will try and get back !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use Replicated tables. You MUST mark your shards with `<internal_replication>true</internal_replication>`.

```
<dwh>
            <!-- shard 01 -->
            <shard>            
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>server1.com</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>test12pwd</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>

            <!-- shard 02 -->
            <shard>           
             <internal_replication>true</internal_replication> 
                <replica>
                    <host>server2.com</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>test12pwd</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
 </dwh>
```

Comment: Seems this was the issue as only one of the server internal_replication was added.